# Can't use svg as React component in React micro-front-end using module-federation

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have React micro-front-end with 4 different projects and 5th as maintainer using module federation (webpack). I just realize I can use SVG as React component in create-react-app but what about in micro-front-end. I have been trying use SVG as React  component one of the project but can't to it.

Is there any different options for module-federation/webpack? Here is my code, I don't know why it's not working.

**My Webpack.config.js:**

```
{
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env", "@babel/preset-react"] },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
```

**import statement for SVG**

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "./logo.svg";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Logo />
      CHK
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**<============> ERROR <============>**

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)